# Spring Security for REST calls

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am getting following error:

> Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

for the code which I am using is:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic auth' + "username" + ":" + "password";
```

When I am trying to run this code in Chrome it is giving me such error but when I am trying to run the same in Internet Explorer its working fine.

Maven dependencies:

```xml
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

`application.properties`:

```
security.user.password=password 
security.user.name=username
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You need to post your full Spring Security config, either XML or Java config.

Comment: I am not using any config files in services side apart from application.properties @PaulNUK

Comment: @Johnk It does look like you need to have some kind of configuration for making the spring security to work like you are expecting. Please see the tutorials here http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5//helloworld-javaconfig.html

Comment: @Zeus Please note that he's using Spring Boot, which will automatically configure all the necessary stuff for basic authentication.

Comment: @Zeus when I tried in internet explorer it is working fine but not in Chrome. I am not getting what changes to make so that it works in Chrome

Comment: @MosheArad I have tried like this `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic auth'+ "InVzZXJuYW1lIiArICI6IiArICJwYXNzd29yZCI=";` But still I am getting same error